# Undo replace task manager on R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-manager

I used the option in System Internals process explorer to replace task manager. Now task manager does not load nor does process explorer, but an error for taskmgr gives the path of taskmgr.exe and then states perimeter incorrect.

How can I undo the replace task manager option?

Comment: Is the error really 'perimeter incorrect'?  Or is that parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jay- check this link here, there are a couple of different solutions:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/replace-task-manager_topic21733.html

Answer (score 4):

I have also found a way to set the Start Task Manager option to run Process Explorer. Go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe
```

And in the entry named "Debugger" enter the path to the procexp.exe or procexp64.exe executable, including " at the beginning an the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe in your registry to restore your original system task manager